# How do I convert a Hexidecimal string to a Byte Array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, hex, type-conversion

I have a string representing a hexidecimal value: `"46-C9-08-B6-E8-F3-47-CF-53-2A-77-02-C9-19-7F"`

I want to convert this to a byte array so it looks something like this: `{&H46, &HC9, &H8, &HB6, &HE8, &HF3, &H47, &HCF, &H53, &H2A, &H77, &H2, &HC9, &H19, &H7F}`

How do I do this?

Comment: What data type is that hex value stored as?

Comment: I am taking the string from a textbox as 46-C9-08-B6-E8-F3-47-CF-53-2A-77-02-C9-19-7F

Comment: *What have you tried?*

Comment: I put the code in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/4zQiiYZt

Answer (score 3):

Split the string and parse the hexadecimal numbers:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = input.Split("-"c).Select(Function(n) Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(n, 16))).ToArray()
```

Comment: If you could explain this a bit more in depth as im new to this I would appreciate it. The word "Input" gets underlined when I paste this code.

Comment: input is a string holding your value you want to convert.