# How to read first n characters of a byte stream? And compare it with string

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have stored files in database in a column of varbinary type. Files look something like .. 
`"0xFFD8FFE......."` in the database. Before downloading these files I want to first check the first n characters such as first `eight characters` to find out if they match `"0xFFD8FF"` if they do I will save the file as ".jpg" and so on. 
How can i do so??I tried many things such as

```
Byte[] threeBytes = new Byte[] { objData[0], objData[1], objData[2], objData[3], objData[5] };      if (objTable.Rows[0]["img"].ToString().StartsWith("0xFFD"))
    {
        strFileToSave += ".jpg";
    }
```

But I am unable to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to compare first `n` chars from bytes. You can use `SequenceEqual` to achieve it.

```
var firstNBytes = bytesFromDatabase.Take(n);
var bytesToCompare = new byte[]{ 0,1,2};//Whatever build your bytes

bool equal = firstNBytes.SequenceEqual(bytesToCompare);
```

Comment: I am not sure if i can compare byte stream with "0xFFD8FFE" with your code..I just want to check if the first n characters(as they appear in database) are same as "0xFFD8FFE"?

Comment: What do you meant by byte stream? try my code, that should work

Comment: I am unable to understand `var bytesToCompare = new byte[]{ 0,1,2};` 
What am i supposed to replace it with?

Comment: For example if you'd like to compare "SomeText" with first 8 characters then `var bytesToCompare = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SomeText");`

Comment: I tried your code but its returning false although the file do starts with `"0xFFD8FFE"` in the database.
I tried both `var bytesToCompare = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0xFFD8FFE");` and `var bytesToCompare = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("0xFFD8FFE");`

Comment: `0xFFD8FFE` is not a string. it looks like hex number. I'll suggest you to read the file from DB, and look and first 8 chars from it using Debugger, then use those chars

Comment: @Arbaaz Forget about strings and characters. It is *bytes* which you need to look at, as Sriram showed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is meant to augment the one posted by @Sriram.

**To OP:** Here is how you can get `bytesToCompare`:

```
Dim bytesToCompare As Byte() = "FF-D8-FF".Split("-"c).
             Select(Function(n) Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(n, 16))).ToArray()
```

(Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970436/how-do-i-convert-a-hexidecimal-string-to-a-byte-array))

Or do it the other way around, convert input bytes to hex string and compare:

```
Dim hex As String = "0x" & ByteArrayToString(firstNBytes)
If hex = "0xFFD8FF" Then ...

Public Function ByteArrayToString(ba As Byte()) As String
  Dim hex As New StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2)
  For Each b As Byte In ba
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
  Next
  Return hex.ToString()
End Function
```

Implementation of `ByteArrayToString` was [converted from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) to VB.NET (personal preference).